# iOS Text and Image Data Storage

Tags: ios, iphone, storage, xcode4.5

I am building an encyclopaedia-like application for iPhone, and I plan to use lots of formatted text and quite a few images in it. My problem is that I do not really know how to store this information in a well structured and easily accessible manner within the application to be accessible offline right after startup.

I am not really familiar with data storing techniques, I just know the basics stuff like WebView, NSUserDefaults, or simply store text as a string in an Array or Dictionary directly within the code. Obviously, none of these techniques provides exactly what I need; so I need some help.

Can a more experienced iOS developer direct me to a tutorial or give me any help on how to proceed? What technique to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [core data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html) to store the locations of the images and retrieve them. Similarly with the formatted text.